# Conversion error in my Python project

Tags: python, numpy

```
# Python code to demonstrate SQL to fetch data.

# importing the module
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import chisquare

# connect withe the myTable database
connection = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\cep_db.db")

# cursor object
crsr = connection.cursor()


dog= crsr.execute("Select s, ei, ki FROM cep_db_lite1_vc WHERE s IN ('d')")
ans= crsr.fetchall() 

# loop to print all the data
dogData = np.array(ans)
FdogData = dogData[:, 1:]
FdogData.astype(float)
x, y =FdogData[:,0], FdogData[:,1]

# Reshaping
x, y = x.reshape(-1,1), y.reshape(-1, 1)

# Linear Regression Object 
lin_regression = LinearRegression()

# Fitting linear model to the data
lin_regression.fit(x,y)

# Get slope of fitted line
m = lin_regression.coef_

# Get y-Intercept of the Line
b = lin_regression.intercept_

# Get Predictions for original x values
# you can also get predictions for new data
predictions = lin_regression.predict(x)
chi= chisquare(predictions, y)

# following slope intercept form 
print ("formula: y = {0}x + {1}".format(m, b)) 
print(chi)

# Plot the Original Model (Black) and Predictions (Blue)
plt.scatter(x, y,  color='black')
plt.plot(x, predictions, color='blue',linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

---

Data being imported:

```
('d', '-72.70', '3.20')
('d', '-74.81', '2.00')
('d', '-87.60', '5.50')
('d', '-91.38', '2.00')
('d', '-71.80', '2.00')
('d', '-73.10', '2.00')
('d', '-81.20', '2.00')
('d', '-81.40', '2.00')
('d', '-75.70', '5.70')
('d', '-83.50', '5.10')
('d', '-73.90', '2.00')
('d', '-82.60', '2.00')
('d', '-77.30', '2.00')
('d', '-85.10', '2.00')
('d', '-79.70', '2.00')
('d', '-78.70', '2.00')
('d', '-77.90', '2.00')
('d', '-76.80', '2.00')
('d', '-83.80', '2.00')
('d', '-83.90', '2.00')
('d', '-82.00', '4.90')
('d', '-80.00', '4.80')
```

Should be an easy fix I am just a little clueless.

getting the error :

```
"TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'"
```

From my knowledge the script cant covert the letter "d" into float because its a letter and not a number.

How can I ignore the first column in the data after importing it?Pretty sure I sliced it. I just want to be able to create an array with columns 2 and 3 and use them for data analysis/graphing

Comment: What line is throwing the TypeError?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 241, in _decision_function
    dense_output=True) + self.intercept_

  File "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 140, in safe_sparse_dot
    return np.dot(a, b)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'